# How to use the `margin: y x;` shorthand in Tailwind?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

In Tailwind CSS if I use a utility for calc such as:

```
right-[calc(-50vw+50%)]
```

this works as expected. I have some attributes I am trying to add to an element but can't seem to figure out how to get it work using tailwind utilities:

```
 .element {
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`my`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#add-vertical-margin) and [`mx`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#add-horizontal-margin):

```
class="my-0 mx-[calc(-50vw_+_50%)]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like below. you use can square brackets to set custom CSS

```
class="my-0 mx-[calc(-50vw_+_50%)]"
```